# How to format xaml properties' indentations in visual studio 2013?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts, indentation

How can I force `Visual Studio 2013` to indent following code?

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Margin="42"
        Text="yolo"
                        FontSize="42">
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Unfortunatelly
<kbd>CONTROL+K</kbd> <kbd>CONTROL+D</kbd>
and
<kbd>CONTROL+K</kbd> <kbd>CONTROL+F</kbd>
don't work...

I know that I can rewrite it to

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Margin>42</TextBlock.Margin>
        <TextBlock.FontSize>42</TextBlock.FontSize>
        yolo
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

but i don't want to do this this way.

### Update

I can't install [Xaml Styler](http://xamlstyler.codeplex.com/) according to @Mashton's answer, because I've got following [error](http://wklej.org/id/1298596/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know would be to use an extension, such as [Xaml Styler](http://xamlstyler.codeplex.com/), which will break a Xaml onto new lines for each attribute. Other plugins exist, I'm sure, which will give you more control.

Comment: I have it installed in VS2013 premium and it works just fine.

Comment: in VS2013 Tools > Extensions and Updates search for "Xaml Styler". Install. Win.

Comment: When I type 'xaml styler' in Extensions and Updates search bar I see only 'Behaviors SDK (XAML)', which is instaled. And It still doesn't format my sample code with ^f nor ^d

Comment: Sounds like you're searching in the installed section of 'extensions and updates' and not the online section ...